# I only get 500 status in Rails Production env

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, sass, webpacker

It seemed to work for a moment but then again only gives me 500 both on local and heroku. Maybe it is because I am using sass?
Logs:

[image: Logs saying webpacker doesn't find stylesheet]

Repo: https://github.com/adelmuursepp/adel_portfolio_site

Comment: [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied and offer poor usability. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. We're not going to go off-site to dig through your code. Questions must be self-contained. Please include the relevant code _here_, directly in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is telling you that Webpacker cannot find a stylesheet named "stylesheet". It looks like, in your application layout, you have the wrong name for your stylesheet bundle; the name isn't "stylesheet", it's "application" ([source](https://github.com/adelmuursepp/adel_portfolio_site/blob/07fe6105099b1aecc4f68eb0bbdaf81062129780/app/views/layouts/application.html.haml#L12)).

The line should read:

```
= stylesheet_pack_tag "application"
```

The canonical name "application" maps to the name of the pack file you are using as Webpack's entry point in `app/javascript/packs` which I can see in your source is `application.js`.